# Entity Framework 5 is sending back the wrong data

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-5

I have a very serious issue with EF sending back the wrong data. I know its wrong because I can run the same query against the same table in management studio and get a completely different result.

I did research the problem and found that some people were able resolve the issue by adding:

```
*DbContextSummary.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, result);*
```

When I try adding that I get this error:

> *The element at index 0 in the collection of objects to refresh has a null EntityKey property value or is not attached to this ObjectStateManager.*

After I got that error I tried to do: DbContextSummary.Attach(result) and I received another error.

What is the proper solution and why does this happen?

**Relevant Code (without the refresh call):**

```
Private _dbContextSummary As BudgetEntities

     Public ReadOnly Property DbContextSummary() As BudgetEntities
            Get
                If _dbContextSummary Is Nothing Then
                    _dbContextSummary = New BudgetEntities
                End If
                Return _dbContextSummary
            End Get
        End Property

     <WebMethod()> _
        Public Function GetSummaryData(ByVal month As String, ByVal year As String, ByVal expenseLine As String, ByVal organization As String) As List(Of SummaryModel)
            Dim result As List(Of SummaryModel) = Nothing

result = (From s In DbContextSummary.FPRs _
                    Where s.FY = year _
                    Where s.Month = month _
                    Where s.FPRLine = expenseLine _
                    Where s.VP = organization
                    Group s By s.MgrID, s.ProgAdm, s.FinanceNumber, s.FinanceNumberName Into g = Group _
                    Order By g.FirstOrDefault.MgrLastName, g.FirstOrDefault.ProgAdm Ascending
                    Select New SummaryModel With { _
                        .Actual = g.Sum(Function(a) a.Actual), _
                        .Plan = g.Sum(Function(p) p.Plan), _
                        .YTDActual = g.Sum(Function(ya) ya.YTDActual), _
                        .YTDPlan = g.Sum(Function(yp) yp.YTDPlan), _
                        .FinanceNumber = g.FirstOrDefault.FinanceNumber, _
                        .FinanceNumberName = g.FirstOrDefault.FinanceNumberName, _
                        .MgrLastName = g.FirstOrDefault.MgrLastName + ", " + g.FirstOrDefault.MgrFirstName, _
                        .PlanYearTotal = g.FirstOrDefault.PlanYearTotal, _
                        .ProgAdm = g.FirstOrDefault.ProgAdm _
                        }).ToList()
Return result
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is the proper solution and why does this happen?

Simply put, there is no proper solution in your scenario. `Refresh` is not applicable at all after you have performed a projection (`select new`) into a type (`SummaryModel`) that isn't an entity. Your `result` collection does not contain entities but `SummaryModel`s. You neither can apply `Refresh` nor `Attach` to this collection or its elements. Both methods are intended to work with model entities: `Refresh` updates properties of an already *attached* entity from the data store and `Attach` adds an entity to the context in state `Unchanged`.

I suggest that you open a new question and describe why you think that "*EF is sending back the wrong data*" and try to solve *this* problem. It's unlikely that *re-loading* provides correct data when *loading* delivers a wrong result.

Comment: Thanks Slauma! After looking into the problem closer I think the problem relies elsewhere.